# Perché si dice becco per dire bocca?

Tags: word-usage, etymology

***[Becco](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/becco1/)*** viene spesso usato in locuzioni con riferimento alla bocca. L'analogia è chiara ma mi chiedo se questi modi di dire abbiano un'origine precisa, antichi modi di dire (greci o latini)  o la commedia dell'arte ad esempio.

Becco:

In alcune locuzioni famigliari,  indica scherzosamente  la bocca dell’uomo:

> - ***bagnarsi il becco***, bere vino; ***mettere il becco***  in un affare, in un discorso, voler dire la propria, interloquire, soprattutto senza esserne richiesti o senza intendersene; ***aprire il becco***, parlare, dire qualcosa; ***chiudere il becco***, smettere di parlare, stare zitto (spec. in forma imperativa: chiudi il becco tu!); ***senza batter becco,*** senza aprire bocca, senza parlare; ***a becco asciutto***, senza niente: restare, rimanere, tornare a becco asciutto.

Treccani.it

Comment: In che senso questa domanda è "too broad"? Si tratta di una domanda di carattere etimologico.

Comment: come mai ti interessano i modi di dire con _becco_ e non quelli che riguardano, ad esempio, gli artigli, tipo **affilare gli artigli** o **tirare fuori gli artigli**? Forse capire il perché del tuo interesse aiuta anche a dare la giusta risposta.

Comment: @LuciaBentivoglio - le espressioni che si rifanno a delle metafore sono molte, questa dell'uso di *becco* mi incuriosisce più di altre. L'origine potrebbe essere comune a quella a cui fai riferimento tu.

Comment: ci sono alti usi ancora + singolari per becco: non avere il becco di un quattrino o per indicare l'essere tradito/fregato: becco= tradito dalla donna. mi hanno fatto becco (mi hanno tradito)

Comment: @giammin - si, ma putroppo le domande di carattere etimologico non generano molto interesse  in questo sito.

Comment: un elenco di modi di dire: http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/B/becco_.shtml  e  http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/B/becco.shtml

Answer (score 5):

Il Dizionario filosofico-pratico della lingua Italiana compilato da Vincenzo Tuzzi lo spiega per benino. Gli uccelli mangiano con il becco, così come fa l'uomo con le labbra. Il naso dell'uomo "sporgente dalla faccia e appoggiato sulle labbra forma una specie di becco"; oltre alla similitudine della forma serve anche all'azione del cibarsi allo stesso modo che fanno gli uccelli col becco. Così il becco in senso proprio resta agli ucceli e nel senso figurato agli uomini. Per questo "il becco" è entrato nei modi di dire e ha sostituito "la bocca" umana.