# Qual è questo uso del verbo "rifarsi"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs

Questa frase in un commento a [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/6252) ha attirato la mia attenzione perché non capivo l'uso che se ne fa del verbo "rifarsi":

> Le espressioni che *si rifanno* a delle metafore sono molte

Quello che ho trovato di più simile alla frase precedente nella [voce "rifare" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rifare/) è questa accezione:

> *rifarsi a qualcosa, a qualcuno*, riallacciarsi, prendere spunto: *molti drammi (o drammaturghi) moderni si rifanno alla tragedia greca (o ai tragici greci)*; *vorrei ora rifarmi a un’obiezione polemica del mio avversario*.

Tuttavia, se questa è l'interpretazione corretta della frase sopra citata, non riesco a capirla molto bene. In che senso le espressioni si riallacciano o prendono spunto dalle metafore?

Comment: *Le espressioni che si rifanno a metafore*; il partitivo è superfluo e brutto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oltre a quello che hai scritto nella tua domanda, aggiungerei che rifarsi può anche essere interpretato come "fare riferimento a".

Nel caso della frase da te citata:

> Le espressioni che si *rifanno* a delle metafore sono molte

Vuol dire che molte espressioni fanno a riferimento delle metafore.

Ti porto un esempio, che magari può essere più esplicativo:

Partiamo dalla metafora:

> Giuseppe è un pallone gonfiato

L'espressione comune è:

> Essere un pallone gonfiato

Quindi, dalla metafora, abbiamo ricavato (facendo riferimento alla stessa) una espressione.

Comment: Capisco, grazie. Comunque, mi sembra curioso che questa accezione non appaia nel vocabolario Treccani.

Comment: In questo senso è lo stesso di "riferirsi a"?

Comment: Esatto, puoi leggerlo come "Le espressioni che si riferiscono a delle metafore sono molte"